# WPF: how to bind lines to UI elements?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, pixelsense

I use this method to bind a Line to the center of two ScatterViewItems:

```
private void BindLineToScatterViewItems(Shape line, ScatterViewItem origin, ScatterViewItem destination)
        {
            // Bind line.(X1,Y1) to origin.ActualCenter
            BindingOperations.SetBinding(line, Line.X1Property, new Binding { Source = origin, Path = new PropertyPath("ActualCenter.X") });
            BindingOperations.SetBinding(line, Line.Y1Property, new Binding { Source = origin, Path = new PropertyPath("ActualCenter.Y") });

            // Bind line.(X2,Y2) to destination.ActualCenter
            BindingOperations.SetBinding(line, Line.X2Property, new Binding { Source = destination, Path = new PropertyPath("ActualCenter.X") });
            BindingOperations.SetBinding(line, Line.Y2Property, new Binding { Source = destination, Path = new PropertyPath("ActualCenter.Y") });
        }
```

But now I'd like to bind it from the bottom from one ScatterViewItem to the top of the another ScatterViewItem:
[image]

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could:

1. Use a `IValueConverter` that takes the bounding rectangle of the view item and a converter parameter to specify the side to calculate the center from.

   ```
   public enum MidpointSide { None, Left, Top, Right, Bottom }

   public class MidpointConverter : IValueConverter
   {
       private bool returnY;
       public MidpointConverter(bool returnY)
       {
           this.returnY = returnY;
       }

       public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
           object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
       {
           var scatter = value as ScatterViewItem;
           var side = (MidpointSide)parameter;
           var center = scatter.ActualCenter;
           var halfW = scatter.ActualWidth / 2.0;
           var halfH = scatter.ActualHeight / 2.0;

           Point point = null;
           switch (side)
           {
           case MidpointSide.Left:
               point = new Point(center.X - halfW, center.Y);
               break;
           case MidpointSide.Top:
               point = new Point(center.X, center.Y - halfH);
               break;
           case MidpointSide.Right:
               point = new Point(center.X + halfW, center.Y);
               break;
           case MidpointSide.Bottom:
               point = new Point(center.X, center.Y + halfH);
               break;
           default:
               return null;
           }

           return this.returnY ? point.Y : point.X;
       }

       public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
           object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
       {
           throw new NotImplementedException();
       }
   }
   ```

   The converter you would use would be:

   ```
   var x = new MidpointConverter(false), y = MidpointConverter(true);

   BindingOperations.SetBinding(line, Line.X1Property,
       new Binding { Source = origin, Converter = x, ConverterParameter = MidpointSide.Bottom });
   BindingOperations.SetBinding(line, Line.Y1Property,
       new Binding { Source = origin, Converter = y, ConverterParameter = MidpointSide.Bottom });

   // Definitely more heavyweight than just changing the `ZIndex`
   // You run into the problem that you can't bind the 'start' and 'end'
   // of a line, only X1/Y1 and X2/Y2 making this converter involved
   ```
2. Keep the same `ActualCenter` bindings, but make the `ZIndex` of the line below that of the rectangles. Using this approach will likely keep you from having to detect if one `ScatterViewItem` moves in such a way that needs to change the side used in the converter.

Comment: Thanks a converter is what i need.But how can I add it to the source code in the question?

Comment: Option 2 would result in a slight offset from the center though, proportional to the rectangle height.

Comment: @Roflcoptr: I'll update. @Steven Jeuris: agreed, and I would stipulate that given its simplicity it is worth the possible "visual" discrepancy.

Answer (score 1):

```
  BindingOperations.SetBinding(line, Line.X1Property, new Binding { Source = origin, Path = new PropertyPath("ActualCenter.X"),Converter=converter });
```

is there a reason this wouldnt work to set the converter?