# Data binding NaN

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, pixelsense

I'm using the code from the answer here [WPF: how to bind lines to UI elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009157/wpf-how-to-bind-lines-to-ui-elements)  And I'm getting "Value produced by BindingExpression is not valid for target property.; Value='NaN'". The only difference between my code and in the link is that I don't set `Point point = null;` just `Point point;` because it produces a convertion problem. 
The MidpointConcerter.cs is exactyl the same as in the link. My method to bind:

```
    private void BindLineToScatterViewItems(Line line, ScatterViewItem StartItem, ScatterViewItem EndItem)
        {
            var x = new MidpointConverter(false);
            var y = new MidpointConverter(true);

            BindingOperations.SetBinding(line, Line.X1Property,
               new Binding { Source = StartItem, Converter = x, ConverterParameter = MidpointSide.Bottom });
           BindingOperations.SetBinding(line, Line.Y1Property,
                new Binding { Source = StartItem, Converter = y, ConverterParameter = MidpointSide.Bottom });
//old in the middle
BindingOperations.SetBinding(line, Line.X2Property,
                                        new Binding { Source = EndItem, Path = new PropertyPath("ActualCenter.X") });
            BindingOperations.SetBinding(line, Line.Y2Property,
                                         new Binding { Source = EndItem, Path = new PropertyPath("ActualCenter.Y") });
        }
```

Can someone help me and say whats wrong and how I can fix it?

Comment: Probably best to show us some code here I think, also could you paste the whole binding exception? And you are right to not set Point point = null; since that wouldn't even compile.

Comment: System.Windows.Data Error: 5 : Value produced by BindingExpression is not valid for target property.; Value='NaN' BindingExpression:Path=ActualCenter.X; DataItem='ScatterViewItem' (Name='EndItem2'); target element is 'Line' (Name=''); target property is 'X2' (type 'Double')
System.Windows.Data Error: 5 : Value produced by BindingExpression is not valid for target property.; Value='NaN' BindingExpression:Path=ActualCenter.Y; DataItem='ScatterViewItem' (Name='EndItem2'); target element is 'Line' (Name=''); target property is 'Y2' (type 'Double')

Comment: If you break point that method is the parameter line == null?

Comment: Hmmm, maybe give us some of the XAML so we can see the bindings, in the mean time drink some beer.. that usually helps the diagnosis process.

Comment: In the MidpointConverter Class the X and Y of point are NaN

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13566293/connecting-scatterviewitems-with-a-line 
It is the same porject.

Answer (score -1):

This is because you variable is not initialized. `Point point = null` is initializing in their code.

```
Point point;
```

merely defines the variable. The only other option you probably have is init it like such

```
Point point = new Point();
```

Because you cannot bind to an uninitialized variable.

[image: screenshot]

[image]

Comment: Point is a structure and so doesn't need to be initialized with new before it can be used, the values in X and Y are also set to zero to start with not NaN.

Comment: Hm, what you're saying makes sense, but it doesn't work either.

Comment: @Andy point does have to be initialized or the compiler complains as you can see in the screenshot I posted above.